# wrong attributes for <pdf:font> xhtml2pdf

Tags: html, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to specify a font for my `xhtml2pdf` file. By i get this error `wrong attributes for <pdf:font>`

I am not sure the correct way to specify the attributes for the font?

I have tried searching for a solution to this, but can't find anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Itim&display=swap');
</style>
<style>
@media print {
    .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; } /* page-break-after works, as well */
}

@page {
    size: a4;
    margin: 1cm;
    @frame footer {
        -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
        bottom: 0cm;
        margin-left: 9cm;
        margin-right: 9cm;
        height: 1cm;
        }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Itim&display=swap');
}
</style>
<body>
<p style="font-size:1.3rem;font-family: Itim,sans-serif;">We have generated your PDF!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try one font here: `font-family: Itim,sans-serif` ?
Personally I am using wkhtmltopdf and there font has to be installed on the machine. Maybe you should try installing the font?

Comment: @EgorWexler i now get `Selector name or qualifier expected:: ('', '"@font-face {\\n  fon')` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation on custom fonts](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=font#using-custom-fonts) `xhtml2pdf` only accepts `TrueType font or a Postscript font.` You are trying to use `OTF`.

Try converting your font to `TTF` or `Postscript`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example as-is using wkhtmltopdf + pdfkit and got the generated PDF with the following content and font:

[image]

Is it the result that you looking for? If yes and you're not really stuck to xhtml2pdf - I can suggest using pdfkit + wkhtmltopdf.